# instagram api results not displaying on server but displaying on localhost

Tags: php, instagram-api

I am having a problem with displaying Images from Instagram onto my website.  Everything works perfectly fine while testing on localhost, but once I upload the code to a server, the images are no longer displayed, and I'm getting a number of errors (which I have listed at the end).

This is the code I'm using to get the images:

```
<?php
                        // Supply a user id and an access token
                        $userid = "1698502975";
                        $accessToken = "250436950.8386f68.5be5542d7ede4f0790cfe906c118b6ad";
                        // $tags = "GraphicDesign";

                        // Gets our data
                        function fetchData($url){

                             $ch = curl_init();
                             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
                             $result = curl_exec($ch);
                             curl_close($ch); 
                             return $result;
                        }

                        $result = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}&count=30");
                        $result = json_decode($result);
                    ?>

                        <?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
                            <a class="lightboxX35" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img id="slides" src="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"></a>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
```

The errors that I'm getting:

> **Error 1**: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]:
>   https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by
>   allow_url_fopen=0 in
>   /home/uirqxukx/public_html/TestArea/LuxuriousM/instagramimages.php on
>   line 32
>
> **Error2**:  PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1698502975/media/recent/?access_token=250436950.1677ed0.fba7f937e8ad45aeb16d5ae49e2d6af7&count=30)
>   [function.file-get-contents]:
>   failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in
>   /home/uirqxukx/public_html/TestArea/LuxuriousM/instagramimages.php on
>   line 32
>
> **Error 3** PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/uirqxukx/public_html/TestArea/LuxuriousM/instagramimages.php on
>   line 36
>
> **Error 4**: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/uirqxukx/public_html/TestArea/LuxuriousM/instagramimages.php on
>   line 36

Comment: Your error messages say it all - `https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0`

Comment: How would I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is turn your `allow_url_fopen` to `On`. Since your host doesn't have it on by default.

You can start by trying to turn it on in your `.htaccess` file, with this:

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

If that doesn't work, you can alternatively try creating your own custom `php.ini` file with this:

```
allow_url_fopen = On;
```